# Woocommerce - Change products order on front page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

does somebody know, how I can change the order products are displayed, only for my front page? I changed the default ordering to custom and now I want to order the products on my front page by date. Any ideas?

Thanks so far

Answer (score 0):

You have option to change products order in admin

admin->woocommerce->settings
 In the setting see the products tab. 
 selecting order in the **Default Product Sorting**

Comment: Hi @kanmani, yeah I know that. I already changed the Product sorting and everything works fine. But now I want to change the sorting only (!) on my home page to a different one then on the other pages (archives etc). So I may need some sort of filter or such, wich I can call when on home? (To change the sorting programmatically)